# Why is my PHP-generated RSS declaring rogue tags?

Tags: php, rss

This is my code which I expected to generate normal RSS. However, after each `<item>` there's a `</channel></rss><?xml version="1.0"?><rss version="2.0">`. What do I need to change so that this is only declared at the end of the script as it should be?

Do let me know if I've missed out any important information.

```
function jobscrape($title, $link, $root, $description, $job_location) {

header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss/>');
$xml->addAttribute("version", "2.0");
$channel = $xml->addChild("channel");

$channel->addChild("title", $title);
$channel->addChild("link", $link);
$channel->addChild("description", "This is a description");
$channel->addChild("language", "en-us");

$html = file_get_contents($link);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

if(!empty($html)) {

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); // remove errors for yucky html
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $row = $xpath->query($job_location);

    if ($row->length > 0) {

        foreach ($row as $job) {

            $jobs = array();
            $entries = array();

            $jobs['title'] = $job->nodeValue;
            $jobs['description'] = "This is a description";
            $jobs['link'] = $job->getAttribute('href');

            array_push($entries,$jobs);

            foreach ($entries as $entry) {

                $item = $channel->addChild("item");
                $item->addChild("title", $entry['title']);
                $item->addChild("link", $entry['link']);
                $item->addChild("description", $entry['description']);

            }

            echo $xml->asXML();

        }
    }
    else { echo "row is less than 0";}
}

else {
    echo "this is empty";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create *one* XML document, add all your items to that document, and call `->asXML();` on the complete document *at the end* (instead of on each fragment every time you go around the loop).